# Add Single Sign On For a New Web

Tags: php, session, ldap

I have 3 webs and have integration single `sign-on using LDAP`. I want to add one web more for `single sign-on`, but I can't take the session from one folder to another folder. Maybe anyone knows how to get the `session from another` folder. The server still same, but different folder

Comment: sessions are user\domain (careful with sub domains) specific, not folder specific

Comment: @smith my single sign on using ldap and this my ldap server '10.0.0.59'

Comment: then i want to add my new web for single sign-on this just for internal not public so example **10.0.0.59/portal** then i want to make sso for this web **10.0.0.59/myweb** i just want to get session. following mistakes _undefined variable session_ still can't get session variable from another folder